# Describe a $3$-dimensional solid whose symmetry group is isomorphic to $D_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Describe a $3$-dimensional solid whose symmetry group is isomorphic to $D_5$.

Would a pentagonal frustum satisfy this?  I can't think of any other rotations or reflections that could exist for this shape, or any other shape that would satisfy this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a (regular) pentagonal frustum would satisfy this.  Since the two pentagonal faces of the frustum do not have the same size, any element of the symmetric group must preserve these faces.  Hence the symmetric group is, "at most", the symmetric group of a pentagon, which is $D_5$.  Since all five rotations and five reflections preserve the frustum, we are done.

Another choice of solid with symmetric group $D_5$ would be a regular pentagonal pyramid.

Comment: Sir, in the second example given by you ( regular pentagonal pyramid), I can easily see all rotational symmetries ( the line passing through top of pyramid to center of base give all five rotational symmetries am i correct?) But what are reflectional symmetries? Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a solid which is a pentagonal prism, but with the pentagonal faces twisted by an angle that is not a multiple of 36° (e.g. 7°); the square faces are replaced with two triangles such that the overall solid is convex. This is similar to the construction of the [Schönhardt polyhedron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhardt_polyhedron) and is chiral; the symmetry group of this solid is $D_5$, generated by

- a rotation through 72° on an axis through the pentagonal faces' centres
- a rotation of 180° that swaps the two pentagonal faces

Note that "reflect through middle plane and rotate through 36°" is not a symmetry, as it changes the handedness.

Comment: There's only one reflection in that transformation. It changes the handedness and is not a symmetry. I have provided an explicit construction of the solid.

Comment: Thanks for the link, now your definition is clear.